# Can I create new ActiveRecord model with parent model & child model IN BULK?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, activerecord

I want to create some ActiveRecord models via ONE METHOD.

My records are below.

```rb
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
  has_many :teams
  has_many :participations
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :participations
  has_many :teams, through: :participations
end

class Team < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :participations
  has_many :users, through: :participations
end

class Participation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :team
end
```

My Environments.

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.4.5p335 (2018-10-18 revision 65137) [x86_64-darwin17]
$ rails -v
Rails 5.0.7.1
```

I tried this. But got an error raised.

```rb
u = User.create(
  company: Company.create,
  teams: [
    Team.create(company: Company.create)
  ]
)
```

```
irb(main):021:0* u.errors
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00007faf7f5668b0 @base=#<User id: nil, company_id: 25, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:participations=>["is invalid"]}, @details={:participations=>[{:error=>:invalid}]}>
irb(main):022:0> u.participations
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Participation id: nil, company_id: nil, user_id: nil, team_id: 15, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]>
```

Can I create some record by ONE LINE?? or can NOT??

Comment: You can use a gem such as [bulk_insert](https://github.com/jamis/bulk_insert). But it won't run your model-level validations (though, you could possibly run them manually before the bulk insert). ActiveRecord doesn't support bulk imports, to my knowledge. So your options are to either use a loop (via some wrapper method if you desire), or to do bulk insert in SQL, skipping ActiveRecord.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I know bulk_insert. But I can NOT solve my problem by that gem. My problem is NOT to import a model as multiple records, but import some multiple models by one create method... :(

Comment: If your question is whether or not ActiveRecord supports this - then I'm afraid the answer is no. However, if you don't mind creating the records in a loop, then you can make a utility method to do it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this in one line. You are trying to instantiate and pass an entire Company object where only an id is needed. Additionally, there is no way to attach the user_id to this Company because the User has not yet been created.

You could do all of this inside of a single method, but it’s probably a bad idea for a whole host of reasons. I’d recommend breaking your logic into multiple methods that are easily testable and maintainable.

Comment: I appreciate your comment :)

I understand your idea that one line is anti-pattern.
And I broke that method to multi-line.

```rb
company = Company.create;
teams = [Team.create(company: company)];
user = User.create(
  company: company,
  teams: teams
)
```
But I still got same error...
How can I create Participate record via ActiveRecord::Relation ??